# Can you rename certain strings using SwiftGen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftgen

I'm using swiftgen to generate some enums for my iOS app but the strings that we use have words in them like... "something_string_something" or "something_float_something".

This means that when the enums are generated it creates...

```
public enum String {
...
}

public enum Float {
...
}
```

And then the corresponding functions that use variables like...

```
public enum Something {
  public static func name(_ p1: Int) -> String {}
}
```

Then have a compile error because the compiler thinks that the `String` in the return type is actually the `public enum String` and not just standard Swift `String`.

Is it possible to define alternative keys in this case? Like if I wanted it to out using `public enum Strng` and `public enum Flt` instead to avoid the collision?

Obviously, if I could change the originating strings I would but they are not so easy to change in a mature project like the one I'm working on.

Comment: I'd go with a custom parser maybe: https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/blob/stable/Documentation/Parsers/strings.md Maybe explicit the expected type, so it's using `Something.String` instead of `Swift.String`. Maybe there is a template for that.

Comment: @Larme Ah, I didn't know it was possible to use a custom parser. Thanks, I'll take a look at that. 

Answer (score 0):

Following @Larme's advice I created my own custom template using this documentation... https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/blob/stable/Documentation/Articles/Creating-custom-templates.md

I copied the pre-made template I wanted to use and then changed it in a few places to add `Swift.` to several of the types.

So now instead of using `String`, `Int`, `Float`, etc... it uses `Swift.String`, `Swift.Int`, `Swift.Float` and generates and builds with no issues.

Thanks @Larme

Comment: Maybe it's even worth a PR on SwiftGen to have its template use Swift prefix since it wouldn't hurt to ensure that the returned type is indeed `Swift.String` and some values are `Swift.Int` etc when there are placeholders.